# Apache Drill Returning Gibberish via ODBC?

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, apache-drill

I'm trying to write a python script that connects to Apache Drill using the pyodbc module.  I'm able to successfully connect to drill, however when I attempt a query I get a strange error that looks like something to do with character encoding.  I've attached my code below, and I'm using Python 3.4.  I should add that I've tried this with and without Pandas and got the same error, so I think that the error is somewhere in the ODBC, but I have zero experience with ODBC.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

MY_DSN = "DRIVER=/opt/mapr/drillodbc/lib/universal/libmaprdrillodbc.dylib;Host=localhost;Port=31010;ConnectionType=Direct;Catalog=Drill;Schema=mfs.views;AuthenticationType=No Authentication"
conn = pyodbc.connect(MY_DSN, autocommit=True)
employee_query = "SELECT * FROM cp.`employee.json`"
data = pd.read_sql( employee_query, conn )
```

Here is the error:

> Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
>   //anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
>      1471             else:
>   -> 1472                 cur.execute(*args)
>      1473             return cur
>
> Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [MapR][Drill] (1040) Drill failed to execute the query: ����������������\n[30027]Query execution error. Details:[ \nPARSE ERROR: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "\ufffd" (65533), after : ""\n\n\n[Error Id: 669ea9b9-34d6-4281-8898-57e8d0 (1040) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Answer (score 0):

Changing the encoding to utf-i6 in `.mapr.drillodbc.ini` fixed this problem for me:

```
[Driver]
DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16
```

Comment: I tried making that change and restarting drill, but I got the same error.  Are there maybe other config variables somewhere else which might need to be set?

Comment: having the same issue.  I'll post back if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with the default unixODBC driver build.  When I installed the unixODBC drivers from source, https://code.google.com/p/odbc/wiki/InstallingUnixODBC, everything worked.  docker to be posted shortly.